# Is there a simple way to get tooltips to work on the elements of a PopupMenu?

Tags: gui-construction

I want my PopupMenu items to be short (codes), with tooltips to provide a longer description if the user hovers over the location.  The direct approach, to wrap each item in a Tooltip, does not produce the desired effect, e.g.

```
PopupMenu[Dynamic[var],{Tooltip["x","This is x"],Tooltip["y","This is y"]}]
```

Shows "x" and "y" in the dropdown list with no tooltips, but when $var$ is saved in a list, the list maintains the Tooltip wrapper.

My look at [this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42814/is-it-possible-to-show-tooltips-in-a-listpicker-menu) for ListPicker does not seem to provide much hope for a simple solution.  But I hope that there is one, perhaps based on more recent releases.

Comment: I tried forcing it with `EventHandler`, but `PopupMenu` looks like it reaches out to the underlying OS, preventing any kind of `Dynamic` activity.

Comment: @Aisamu - thanks for trying.  I think it would be a really nice feature.